# reduced row echelon form for an infinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, infinite-matrices

It is well-known that the reduced row echelon form for a finite matrix is unique. I am wondering when such a result can be extended to an infinite matrix. Say I have an infinite matrix $A$ in row echelon form already,  so that I can eliminate all nonzero entries above each pivot within a given column in a finite amount of steps (using Gaussian elimination). Will the resulting matrix be unique?

Comment: It's not at all clear o me what it _means_ to say an "infinite matrix"  $B$ is row-equivalent to another infinite matrix $A$. Presumably you meann to allow infinitely many row operations, but what the result of applying infinitely many row operations is not clear. (Also it can't be just a single _sequence_ of row operations, seems like we need to allow a "transfinite sequence" $(E_\alpha)$ for $\alpha$ less than some countable ordinal.) You'd better at least include the _definition_...

Comment: To  my way of thinking you can include something without proof if it's either well known or trivial. Does this qualify? (If you don't know _whether_ something is well known possibly you shouldn't be writing a paper on that topic - there's a definite possibility that you'll say something utterly stupid...)

Comment: Thank you, I narrowed down the scope of the question based on your comment. It sounds like this question is not trivial, so I can't state it in a paper without proof.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but infinite matrices come in many (non-equivalent) forms. Do you mean the simplest one, where the rows are indexed $1,2,3,\ldots$ and so are the columns? (So the matrix has an upper and a left margin but no lower and right ones.) Also, if you allow infinite sequences of row operations, you may want to specify how. I would look at various proofs of the uniqueness of the RREF in the finite case and checking whether they still apply. My hunch is that they do, because I remember the main idea was "what are the ranks of the (finite) northwestern submatrices?".

Comment: Well first, in the current version the closest we come to a definition of the RREF is a procedure for calculating it. Assuming that''s well defined it''s unique, since  the procedure leads to only one matrix.